# Can images in droid be displayed without the use of imageview or the xml file

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, image, imageview

I was wondering if anyone knew if it where possible to dynamically display an image through code pulling it straight from the res folder in eclipse for a droid app without setting up an imageview in the xml file.

I'm still fairly new to droid and programming in general and so far all images I have ever displayed I have used imageview in xml to do it. Curious to know if it were possible to leave xml out of it, and any suggestions how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinearLayout linear=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

ImageView img=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

linear.addView(img);

setContentView(linear);

Answer (score 1):

you can inflate views from Java code using their Java object equivalents. For ImageView:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Context);
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_drawable);
addChildView(imageView); // add it to the screen. if in a fragment, need getView().addChildView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.In xml layout, add id to default layout as **android:id="@+id/layout"**

2.Now in java file :

RelativeLayout layout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.**layout**);  //xml default layout

LinearLayout linear1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());   //dynamically created layout

linear1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);   //adding image to dynamic layout

layout.addView(linear1);   //adding dynamically created layout to default xml layout

Here I am using **LinearLayout** for creating dynamic layout you can use anyone.

Comment: Thanks! This works well. but is this your way of saying that xml can never be removed from the process when displaying images?